# ImageView not reseting to original location after animation

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a swipe recognizer that calls this function when a swipe is detected. The alpha animation works great, but after the animation, the image is not resetting to its original location in the center.

Currently, the image stays on the left.... I've searched all over and it seems that I'm implementing the animation correctly.

I'm using a `RelativeLayout` and `swipeImageView` is an empty imageview in the middle of my layout.

```
swipeImageView.bringToFront();
swipeImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.skip4x));

ObjectAnimator nextGroupLeft = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(swipeImageView, "x", -250f);
nextGroupLeft.setDuration(1000);

ValueAnimator fadeAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(swipeImageView, "alpha", 1f, 0f);
fadeAnim.setDuration(1000);

AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
animSetXY.playTogether(nextGroupLeft, fadeAnim);
animSetXY.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying clearing the animations. When this line is executed, the animations should stop and the ImageView should return to its original state.

```
swipeImageView.clearAnimation();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I tried it and it doesn't work for me.